# what`s the difference between DB.Query() and DB.Prepare()+Stmt.Query() in golang

Tags: go

These two schemes can achieve the same function, so what`s the difference between them? 
reference:
      https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/

Comment: Here is an reference: http://go-database-sql.org/prepared.html

Answer (score 3):

**DB.Query**

> ```
> func (db *DB) Query(query string, args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)
> ```
>
> Query executes a query that returns rows, typically a SELECT. The args are for any placeholder parameters in the query.

By definition this accepts a single query and returns rows to iterate from

**DB.Prepare() + Stmt.Query()**

> ```
> func (db *DB) Prepare(query string) (*Stmt, error)
> ```
>
> Prepare creates a prepared statement for later queries or executions. Multiple queries or executions may be run concurrently from the returned statement
>
> ```
> func (s *Stmt) Query(args ...interface{}) (*Rows, error)
> ```
>
> Query executes a prepared query statement with the given arguments and returns the query results as a *Rows.

Since *DB.prepare* can accept multiple queries and *Stmt.Query* can run them concurrently, this can be used to **run multiple concurrent queries** as well, unlike the *DB.Query* which is used to **execute a single query**

Comment: But I want at a specific point in time to execute a single query, is there a difference between the two? And if I have a certain query which I intend to use several times (with different parameters) but infrequently and not in parallel, should I still prepare a statement? Does it make sense not to close a Stmt throughout the entire lifetime of the application?